Communication via the Internet/mobile phone (Android) <-> PC
I am currently looking for a way to establish communication between my application on my mobile phone (Android) and my Delphi application (12.1).
So far I have tried to establish the communication via UDP, as long as the mobile phone is in the local network with the PC it works.
I have also got as far as sending messages from the mobile phone (mobile data) to the PC via UDP, only replying is currently my problem. (The UDP massage was send to an open Port.)
Now I am looking for a way to reply to the UDP message or for a new approach.

Are you saying that replying to the same IP/port where the message came from is not working? Also, why UDP and not TCP?
